# PCRE / Extended regex library in Java?

Tags: library, java, regex

I'm in need of [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org) functionality for my regular expressions in Java. I've been unable to find such a library. What is an extended library (Hopefully including more of the PCRE constructs and extends of vanilla [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) capabilities)?

Comment: Hmm… could you address libpcre via JNI? Sure, absolutely utterly evil and unportable and unidiomatic…

Answer (score 3):

I have found [JRegex](http://jregex.sourceforge.net/doc-index.html). It seems to include the set of [syntax from Perl5.6 regular expressions](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Misc/perl-5.6.1/pod/perlre.html) (Version 8 `perlre`), with [special syntax](http://jregex.sourceforge.net/syntax.html) for named backreferences and in-pattern comments. However it is not very reliable and runs into infinite loops in typical zero-length matches, which is unfortunate.